# Why undefined method in RSPEC for a call to method in an included module?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

In our rails 3.2.12 app, `model project` needs to use a method `find_config_const` in module `authentify_utility.rb` in `authentify` engine. In `model project`, so there is

```
include Authentify::AuthentifyUtility
```

The method `find_config_const` is called in `model project` as:

```
validates :sales_id, :presence => true,
                       :numericality => {:greater_than => 0} if find_config_const('project_has_sales', 'projectx') == 'true'
```

Here is the error in rspec:

```
project.rb:51:in `<class:Project>': undefined method `find_config_const' for Authentify::AuthentifyUtility:Module (NoMethodError)
```

In module authentify_utility, after method definition, there is a module function declaration for method find_config_const as (to make the method available to others):

```
module_function :find_config_const
```

There is no error when execution of the code except this rspec error. How to fix this error for rspec? Is it a bug in rspec? Thanks for help.

UPDATE:

Definition of the method

```
def find_config_const(param_name, engine=nil, version=nil)
      const_value = nil
      engineConfig = Authentify::EngineConfig.where(:engine_name => engine, :engine_version => version, :argument_name => param_name).first() if engine.present? && version.present?
      engineConfig = Authentify::EngineConfig.where(:engine_name => engine, :argument_name => param_name).first() if engine.present? && version.blank?
      engineConfig = Authentify::EngineConfig.where(:argument_name => param_name).first() if engine.blank? && version.blank?
      const_value = engineConfig.argument_value unless  engineConfig.nil?
      const_value
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you show the definition of `find_config_const`?

Without seeing it, my best guess is that you should not call the method with the module name, since you #include'd it in your model.

Comment: Just updated the post with the definition of the method. The method is to retrieve a value from the db.

Comment: Thanks.  I don't know how it works outside of rspec, but try this in your model:
`if find_config_const('project_has_sales', 'projectx') == 'true'`

Comment: I see the problem: don't include the module in the model. `require` at the top of the file, then call the method the way you originally did: `Authentify::AuthentifyUtility.find_config_const`

Comment: same error. What we did was to define a method validate_sales as: def validate_sales
        return find_config_const('project_has_sales', 'projectx') == 'true'
      end and make it if :validate_sales. Somehow the call to the method find_config_const working from within a method. Don't know why. But it works.

Answer (score 1):

You have to require the module in `spec_helper.rb` or in your spec:

```
require 'authentify/authentify_utility'
```